# iMacros: Pauze after x amount of loops (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, random, wait, imacros

> What I've read so far is that pausing in between loops is only
>   possible in javascript. I have a hard time getting my code to work in
>   Javascript.

**What i want my code to execute:**
Go to a website and click a button. 
Loop trough the sites different sub domains via my datasource text file. 
I want to run 90 loops (going trough 90 sub domains) pause for 1 hour, continue the loop for another 90 and pause again for 1 hour etc etc.. (my datasource text file consists of 1000+ sub domains).

This i my code:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 2); randomNumber;") /*after a button is pushed wait for a random number of seconds*/ 
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE_DELIMITER ;
SET !DATASOURCE data_list.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
URL GOTO=http://www.website.com/{{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Button
WAIT SECONDS={{!var1}}
```

This works fine i can put an x amount of loops and the code Will run just fine. *But i can't / don't know how to pause after 90 loops in javascript.*

This is how far i got in converting my code to javascript:

```
var macro;
var rand = "Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 2)"; /*after a button is pushed wait for a random number of seconds*/ 
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 0" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE ACCOUNTS_NO.txt" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=https://www.website.com/{{!COL1}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Button" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS = {{rand}}" + "\n"; /***this does not seem to work in javascript*/**
iimPlay(macro)
```

The random number in javascript does not work. Also the code to loop for 90 times, pause for 1 hour and continue still needs to be added.

> Can anybody please help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this solution will help:

```
SET !LOOP 1
SET period 90
SET bigVAR1 3600

' /*after a button is pushed wait for a random number of seconds*/ '    
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 2); randomNumber;")
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE_DELIMITER ;
SET !DATASOURCE data_list.txt
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
URL GOTO=http://www.website.com/{{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Button

SET !VAR1 EVAL("({{!LOOP}}%{{period}}) ? {{!VAR1}} : {{bigVAR1}};")
WAIT SECONDS={{!var1}}
```

(As you can see there's no need to convert the macro to JavaScript.)

Comment: Shugar, Wauw thanks bro! I does exactly what I want it to do now. Can't be more thankful and grateful bro!

Comment: Is is possible to add a second "period" ? For example: 
SET period 90 
SET bigVAR1 3600

SET period  20 
SET bigVAR2 120

so it wil stop after 20 loop wait for 120 sec and it wil stip after 90 loops and wait for 3600sec

Comment: Singularity, it's alright. Accepting and upvoting answers is quite enough on 'stackoverflow'.